# there is no application installed for "Graphviz DOT gragh" files in gem5 output

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

I am trying to run a model using gem5 simulator and below packages are already installed:

pip install pydot

pip install pydotplus

sudo apt-get install graphviz

now when I run my model in gem5, one of the output files named "config.dot" do not open and I am getting a message that "there is no application installed for "Graphviz DOT gragh" files".

Are there any packages I should install so i can open this "config.dot" file?

Comment: @karel still getting the same message.  tow files named "config.dot.svg" and "config.dot.pdf" are readable. Only the "config.dot" file has a problem.

Comment: If you want you can upload the "config.dot" file to Google Drive or Dropbox or somewhere like that and I'll try to read it.

Comment: @karel sure..please check below google drive    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-5cZKVgcbY1dCZAuGel8VkCyuhBQTpki/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @karel Thank You so much .. it worked!    Great explanation

Comment: @karel is there any chance that you are a python user? i have some issues and need help.

Comment: I'm a Python user and Python is my highest scoring tag at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @karel how can I contact you please?

Comment: Comment to me anywhere on this page if you have posted a question at Stack Overflow with a link to your question so that I can read it. Please remember that questions at Stack Overflow that don't show what code you tried are usually closed by reviewers as unclear, needs focus, or needs debugging details, whatever reason applies, and copy/paste your code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: @karel i just posted the question and this is the link   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403457/gem5tomcpat-parser-python-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened the config.dot file that you uploaded by double-clicking it and it opened in a the Dot Viewer application and showed the below diagram. You can zoom in on the diagram in Dot Viewer to read the diagram better and view the text in very sharp detail.

[image]

xdot is an interactive viewer for graphs written in Graphviz's dot language. It uses internally the graphviz's xdot output format as an intermediate format, and PyGTK and Cairo for rendering. xdot can be used either as a standalone application from command line or as a library embedded in your Python 3 application.

Features:

- Since it doesn't use bitmaps it is fast and has a small memory footprint.
- Arbitrary zoom.
- Keyboard/mouse navigation.
- Supports events on the nodes with URLs.
- Animated jumping between nodes.
- Highlights node/edge under mouse.

To install XDot in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install xdot
```

Comment: Thank You so much .. it worked! Great explanation