# Gem5ToMcPAT parser Python file

Tags: 20.04, python, xml

I am trying to convert the output of a gem5 simulator model to an XML form that could be used as an input to McPAT simulator (to get power results). The file that does this conversion is a Python file with the help of another XML file.

I run the Python file in Ubuntu 20.04 with the below command:

```
python2 GEM5ToMcPAT.py Gem5_readings/stats.txt Gem5_readings/config.json inorder_arm.xml -o my_output.xml
```

and got the below error message with no my_output.xml results:

```
Reading GEM5 stats from: Gem5_readings/stats.txt
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus0.dcache.avgBlocked::no_mshrs is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus0.dcache.avgBlocked::no_targets is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus0.icache.avgBlocked::no_mshrs is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus0.icache.avgBlocked::no_targets is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus1.dcache.avgBlocked::no_mshrs is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus1.dcache.avgBlocked::no_targets is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus1.icache.avgBlocked::no_mshrs is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus1.icache.avgBlocked::no_targets is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus2.dcache.avgBlocked::no_mshrs is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus2.dcache.avgBlocked::no_targets is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus2.icache.avgBlocked::no_mshrs is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus2.icache.avgBlocked::no_targets is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus3.dcache.avgBlocked::no_mshrs is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus3.dcache.avgBlocked::no_targets is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus3.icache.avgBlocked::no_mshrs is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.cpus3.icache.avgBlocked::no_targets is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.l2.avgBlocked::no_mshrs is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.cpu_cluster.l2.avgBlocked::no_targets is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.mem_ctrls0.dram.writeRowHitRate is nan. Setting it to 0
    Warning (stats): system.mem_ctrls1.dram.writeRowHitRate is nan. Setting it to 0
Reading config from: Gem5_readings/config.json
Reading McPAT template from: inorder_arm.xml
***WARNING: system.cpu does not exist in config.***
     Please use the right config param in your McPAT template file
***WARNING: system.cpu.decodeInputWidth does not exist in config.***
     Please use the right config param in your McPAT template file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GEM5ToMcPAT.py", line 181, in <module>
    main()
  File "GEM5ToMcPAT.py", line 53, in main
    dumpMcpatOut(opts.out)
  File "GEM5ToMcPAT.py", line 80, in dumpMcpatOut
    exprs[i] = str(eval(exprs[i]))
  File "<string>", line 1
    {u'membus': {u'point_of_coherency': True
                                           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: @karel can i send you the files?

Comment: Please provide a link to the files on Google Drive or a similar website, so that I can download them. Also please check if my GitHub link in the question's 2nd paragraph is correct.

Comment: @karel i got the McPAT and the python file from this link:   https://github.com/exarchou/Computer-Architecture/tree/main/Lab_3

Comment: @karel and my files are on the google drive below:    https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rkMCWUTv4gaTMxsQtLfuhnjIY73R--cA?usp=sharing

Comment: @karel the author used pyhton2, so i installed it. When i run this file, i convert to python2 using below command        sudo update-alternatives --config python
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3   2         manual mode

Press  to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:

Comment: I saw that too because I already downloaded all the files from your Google Drive link.

Comment: @karel a colleague of mine told me that i have a missing package or Python library ... Not sure what it could be or how to get it.

Comment: @karel please note that the Gem5 Output Files that i use are the files in the google drive, not the ones from the github link

Comment: GEM5ToMcPAT.py is a poorly written piece of code. There are numerous places in the code where 4 space characters are replaced by a Tab character which generates indentation syntax errors. For this reason I don't trust the code. This turns your question into as programming question and there are so many errors in the code that it would probably be closed at Stack Overflow as "needs focus".

Comment: @karel I thought it is good since he got results :(  , so what is your recommendation please? i need a python parser to get the power readings for my model.

Comment: As far as I no there's no such thing as code recommendations and they are off topic in the Stack Exchange network generally. I'm not sure you can get a usable software recommendation for a Python parser to get the power readings for your model at [Software Recommendations Q&A](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) either because it's too narrow and too specific.

Comment: @karel i will try this...Thanks a lot for your help. It was really helpful..... one last question Karel: how do you make changes in the format  when type a question or a comment? i mean put the commands and codes in the gray box with different style.

Comment: There's a horizontal toolbar at the top of the editor when you edit any post that has a row of several buttons on it. Just select a block of text and click the buttons one by one and see what happens to the selected text.